# How to output data using query builder while eliminating duplicates

Tags: laravel

I have a table of results where there is `adm_no`, `subject_id`, `exam_id` and `score` fields. I inserted the data using the `updateOrCreate` method in laravel 5.4.

When I fetch the data I still get duplicates. e.g. when a user inserts marks for instance 2 students for a given subject and repeats it for the same students and subject I should get the latest row of all results.

Here is a sample of my query:

```php
public function searchStudent()
{
    $exam = Exam::all();
    $term = Term::all();

    $a = Input::get('adm_no');
    $e = Input::get('exam_id');
    $t = Input::get('term_id');
    $y = Input::get('year');

    $results = DB::table('results')
        ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(subject_id)'))
        ->where('adm_no', 'LIKE', '%' . $a . '%')
        ->where('exam_id','LIKE', '%' . $e . '%')
        ->where('term_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $t . '%')
        ->where('year', 'LIKE', '%' . $y . '%')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

    dd($results); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
$results = DB::table('results')
        ->groupBy('subject_id')
        ->where('adm_no', 'LIKE', '%' . $a . '%')
        ->where('exam_id','LIKE', '%' . $e . '%')
        ->where('term_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $t . '%')
        ->where('year', 'LIKE', '%' . $y . '%')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Its still not picking the latest value.    let's say the first record for adm_no: 1 , subject_id :1 and had a score of 35 and a second score for the same student and subject was 40 how can i pick 40 and ignore 35 in my query.

Comment: Oh, this changes the question a bit, try to checkout [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

i did more research on the question and this is what i got working for me.

**Question**

```
      public function searchStudent(){
        $a= Input::get( 'adm_no' );
        $e= Input::get( 'exam_id' );
        $t= Input::get( 'term_id' );
        $y= Input::get( 'year' );
         $results=DB::table('results')->distinct('subject_id')
        ->where( 'adm_no', $a)
        ->where( 'exam_id', $e)
        ->where( 'term_id',$t)
        ->where( 'year',$y)
        ->groupBy('subject_id')
        ->latest('subject_id')
        ->get();
        dd($results);
          }
```